# Are these sentence correct "What things can make you cry?", "What can things make you cry?"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I don't know whether or not these sentence are correct. The following sentence shows below.

"What things can make you cry?"
"What can things make you cry?"

I have found some article about auxiliary verb. The following question "What is different between “What is the dog can do?” and “What can the dog do?” (ELL link [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145696/what-is-different-between-what-is-the-dog-can-do-and-what-can-the-dog-do)).

I still don't know Whether or not the two sentences are right or wrong. I want put a noun in my question like "things" in the example sentences above. I konw "What can make you cry?" is correct.

Please tell me which is right or both of them are right or wrong, and why?

Comment: You can think of the word ***what*** itself as a kind of "noun" (e.g. - *What I like is chocolate,* where ***what = chocolate = [noun]***), so you don't *need* to explicitly provide another noun to go with it. You can just ask ***What makes you cry**?* rather than *What **things** make you cry?*, and this is what most native speakers would usually do.

Comment: It's worth adding that 'What can things make you cry' and 'What is the dog can do' don't make any sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to ask others "what can different things make you anxious?" or "what different things can make you anxious?". I think that I want to emphasize "different things" because I want to interview some people from different country which have something different to our country.

Comment: None of that makes any difference. You could perhaps ask people *What **three things** make you cry [most]?* if you particularly wanted everyone to list ***three*** different things in their answer, but I don't think there's any short natural way to ask *What makes you cry?* with the implication that you want ***at least two different things in each answer***. Even if you ask *What **things** make you cry?*, you might get the one-word answer ***Onions**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers So does that imply that both of the two example sentences are wrong? Does that mean I cannot add "can" if I add that the sentences are wrong?

Comment: You can include ***can*** if you like, but imho it doesn't really serve any purpose. But that's irrelevant to the point you ***seem*** to be asking about (do you need an explicit noun in a question like your example, and if so *how* should that noun be included?). Consider the implications of, say, *Do you know what types of mushroom [**can**] make you ill?* Including ***can*** is genuinely "meaningful", because some people can eat fungi that make other people sick (so it's particularly appropriate if ***you*** there means "people in general", not just the single person being addressed).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So "how should that noun be included?". I have known when I should add "can".

So please tell me where I should put "can".

1 "What things can make you cry?"
2 "What can things make you cry?"

1, 2, or both of 1 and 2.

Comment: Note @simon's comment, pointing out that you've got the syntax of ***can*** completely wrong. But my point here is that ***you don't need to use the modal / auxiliary "can" at all*** in your examples - and in fact it would be better ***not*** to use it. Nor do you need an explicit noun in questions like ***What makes you cry? What do you like to eat?,*** etc.

Comment: I know now. I don't need "can". If I add "can", both "What things can make you cry?" and "What can things make you cry?" are wrong. "What are things can make you cry" correct.